# Lost Polygons after clipping Shapefile using QGIS clip fuction

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, clip

I'm trying to clip the CORINE Land Cover 10 ha Shapefile (https://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/open-data/corine-land-cover-10-ha-clc10.html) with a district shapefile to get my investigation area. Thereby, I extracted the three relevant districts of my investigation from the original district shapefile (https://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/verwaltungsgebiete-1-250-000-ebenen-stand-01-01-vg250-ebenen-01-01.html) with the following code:

```
import geopandas as gpd

districts_germany = gpd.read_file('C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/Master Thesis/Python/Data_New/District Data/vg250_01-01.utm32s.shape.ebenen/vg250_01-01.utm32s.shape.ebenen/vg250_ebenen_0101/VG250_KRS.shp')
districts_fr_em_br = districts_germany.loc[[203, 204, 205], :]
districts_fr_em_br.to_file('C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/Master Thesis/Python/Data_New/District Data/vg250_01-01.utm32s.shape.ebenen/vg250_01-01.utm32s.shape.ebenen/vg250_ebenen_0101/districts_fr_em_br.shp')
```

Then I used the clip function in QGIS with the clc10 shapefile (green) as input layer and the created districts_fr_em_br shapefile (pink) as overlay layer. However, after clipping, some areas of the clipped clc10 shapefile (yellow) are missing. Both shapefiles have the same Coordinate Reference System.

[image]

[image]

It seems to be that polygons, which go beyond the district boundaries, are missing. Is there a way to cut these polygons at the boundary? However, I think also polygons, which are not crossing the border, are missing. Thus, I'm not sure if this is the problem.
I also tried to convert the MultiPolygons to Polygons and clip it afterward. But the same areas are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to the problem was to rasterize the clc shapefile using `Raster > Conversion > Rasterize` in QGIS. Thereby, I had to change the data type of column clc to int. Then I clipped the raster file to my district boundaries `districts_fr_em_br` using `Raster > Extraction > ClipRasterbyMaskLayer` in QGIS. Afterwards, I polygonized it again to avoid the missing areas using `Raster > Conversion > Polygonize`.

[image]